# infinite scrolling not compatible with masonry

Tags: callback, tumblr, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, masonry

I'm having a lot of trouble getting masonry to work alongside infinite scrolling. I've done everything I possibly can do and still nothing. Is there something wrong with my code, or did I just miss something completely?

This is my code:

```
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-infinitescroll/2.0b2.120519/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.2/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.0.4/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/wgijwsy/u2vm2hxv6/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).load( function() {
    $('#content').masonry({
        "itemSelector": ".entry",
        "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer",
    });

$container.infinitescroll({
itemSelector : ".entry",
navSelector : "#pagination",
nextSelector : "#pagination a",
loadingImg : "",
loadingText : "<em></em>",
bufferPx : 10000,
extraScrollPx: 12000,
},
// trigger Masonry as a callback
function( newElements ) {
  var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
});
}
);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are loading infinite-scroll twice (1st and 4th in the following code) and I do not see you are loading jQuery, which should be first. A jsfiddle would help to narrow down other issues.

```
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-infinitescroll/2.0b2.120519/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.2/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.0.4/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/wgijwsy/u2vm2hxv6/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your fiddle will not work. There is no such jquery as version 1.0.2 and your masonry goes to a web page, not a masonry.js file and you haven't loaded imagesloaded or infinitescroll. Set the jquery version under Frameworks and Extensions and then go to (https://cdnjs.com) to get the links to masonry, imagesloaded and infinite-scroll, and load them in the fiddle as external resources. Then we can help you with all the mistakes in your code.

Comment: I've done what you've suggested. I set the jquery version under frameworks, and I've uploaded masonry, imagesloaded, and inifinite-scroll (https://jsfiddle.net/x07u6tex/21/)